# Txt files have unnecessary spaces

Tags: windows, text-editors, notepad, rendering

I am downloading a log file from a security system as txt file, The log contain one or more lines where there is only single space between every 2 words, however, when i downloaded it and opened in notepad, I can see random multiple spaces are added between words.

Can anyone explains why this happens and how can i fix it?

Comment: This will be an issue with the program writing to the log file.

Comment: If the spaces bother you, remove them using a text editor.

Comment: Are you sure they are spaces?  Have you looked at the file in a hex editor and ensured that they are 0x20 ?

Comment: Thanks all, It appears that the raw logs contain these spaces, so I misunderstood the problem

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to load the text file in a text editor that supports regex (regular expression) find and replace (such as Notepad++).  Then find all:

```
[space]+
```

and replace with:

```
[space]
```

where you type a space instead of literally typing `[space]`.

Note that some editors will require regex to be encapsulated in forward slashes.  For these editors, find:

```
/[space]+/
```

and replace with

```
/[space]/
```

Again, substituting a real space for `[space]`.